# How can I calculate the partial derivative using torch.autograd.grad() when the inputs and outputs are batched?

Tags: pytorch, derivative, autograd

I build a network with 2 inputs(namely x1,x2) and 2 outputs(namely y1, y2). I use dataloader to feed the data to my network, and the batch size is 100? How can I get the partial derivative of y1 over x1 and partial derivative of y2 over x2 for every piece of data in the batch?

Here is some of my code:

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()        
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(2, 5)
        self.hidden_layers = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(5, 5) for _ in range(3)])
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(5, 2)        
        self.activation = nn.Tanh()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.activation(self.input_layer(x))        
        for hidden_layer in self.hidden_layers:
            x = self.activation(hidden_layer(x))        
        x = self.output_layer(x)
        return x

model = NeuralNetwork()
train_loader = DataLoader(data, batch_size= 100, shuffle=True)
for epoch in range(iterations):
    for i, (x_train, y_label) in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
        # x_train is 100*2, y_label is 100*2, y_net is 100*2
        x_train = autograd.Variable(x_train, requires_grad=True)
        y_net = model(x_train.float())

        a10 = torch.tensor([1.0,0.0], requires_grad=True)
        a01 = torch.tensor([0.0,1.0], requires_grad=True)
        grad_output1 = torch.ones_like(y_net)
        grad_output1[:, 1] = 0
        dY1dX = autograd.grad(y_net, x_train, grad_outputs=grad_output1, create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]
        grad_output2 = torch.ones_like(y_net)
        grad_output2[:, 0] = 0
        dY2dX = autograd.grad(y_net, x_train, grad_outputs=grad_output2, create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]
```

I am not sure is this is the right way and whether I can get the right partial derivative.